# Present perfect vs Pesent perfect continious vs Present simple vs Past simple. here!

Tags: tense

1) I've known her for ten years.

2) I've been knowing her for ten years.

3) I know her for ten years.

4) I knew her for ten years.

Which of these are is/are correct. Explain it- please.

Answer (score 1):

1) I've known her for ten years.

This is the normal form in most Englishes for an acquaintance which has lasted for ten years and is still continuing (or very recently was - you might say it if she has died very recently)

2) ? I've been knowing her for ten years.

I suspect this may be current in Indian English, which uses continuous forms for verbs which are not used that way elsewhere. But in any other English I'm aware of, this simply would not be said. "Know" can't take a continuous form.

3) * I know her for ten years.

I don't think this is grammatical in any version of English, though it is a mistake you often hear from speakers of various European languages, translating their own idioms.

4) I knew her for ten years.

This is perfectly normal, for an acquaintance which lasted ten years but is now over.

Comment: Would it be OK to say: yes, I do know her.

Comment: @Faizan: yes, you can say "I know her" or "I do know her", but not "I [do] know her for ten years".

Comment: Is this grammatically correct, I had known her for 30 years before she died.

Comment: @Faizan: yes, that is grammatical and normal.

Comment: But, why do we use time expressions with present perfect and past perfect...

Comment: @Faizan: that's a big question. We don't usually use "point of time" expressions with present perfect, but we can use "period of time" expressions with it, especially with "for". Period of time expressions are common with the present perfect continuous (eg "I have been waiting for an hour"); and this applies to the present perfect of verbs like "know" that don't usually take continuous aspects. The past perfect isn't like the present perfect: it's really just a "past in the past", and doesn't always have the specific meaning (continuing relevance) of the present perfect

Comment: This question has not a whiff of effort. I think it should be closed for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

Actually 
Present perfect progressive can't be used 
With non action verbs like

Love ,prefer , know

(State verbs ) you shoud read about it

And sth else

You can use I knew him to refer that 
Relationship 's gone

You can't use I know him for ten years 
This's wrong as I aware

Enjoy the answer

Comment: Please don't use "sth" for "something".